# Time complexity for sorting algorithm

Tags: python, time

I am trying to find what values of k gives a linear time complexity for an algorithm that sorts numbers in a list in ascending order. I have found that O(1) values of k makes the algorithm O(n), but I have heard that other values of k exist that I can't find. The Pseudocode is pasted below. Any help would be appreciated!

`""" PSEUDOCODE
    Function sort(a)
    A <- new dict
    K <- new array
    M <- new array
    For i in a
        A.add {i:0}
    For i in a
        A[i] <- A[i]+1
    For key in A.keys
        K <- add key
    K <- Quicksort (K)

    For k in K
    M = M + [k]*A.value(k)
    return M
"""`

Comment: You should get better answers in the computer science stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Your first 3 loops are O(a) so O(3a) so far

Quicksort is O(alog(a)) at best/average, O(a^2) worst (represent as QS)

The fourth loop is O(a)

All together:

O(3a) + O(QS) + O(a)

= O(4a) + O(QS)

= O(a) + O(QS)

= O(QS)